# Custom ObservableCollection<string> with additional functions

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

I want to create a custom `ObservableCollection<string>` to use with MVVM in WPF. My actual goal is to extend the standard `ObservableCollection<string>` by two properties, which return the selected index and the selected item, as well as by a method that checks whether a given string is in the Collection. It currently looks like this:

```
public class MyStringCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    private int _selectedIndex;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _strings;

    public MyStringCollection() : base()
    {
        _selectedIndex = 0;
        _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Index selected by the user
    /// </summary>
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set { _selectedIndex = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Item selected by the user
    /// </summary>
    public string Selected
    {
        get { return _strings[SelectedIndex]; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if MyStringCollection contains the specified string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">The specified string to check</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Contains(string str)
    {
        return (_strings.Any(c => (String.Compare(str, c) == 0)));
    }        
}
```

Even though `MyStringCollection` inherits from `ObservableCollection<string>`, the standard methods, such as `Add`, `Clear`, etc., won't work. Of course, that is because I create a separate instance `_strings` each time I create an instance of MyStringCollection.

My question is how to add/clear elements to/from my `ObservableCollection<string>()` without adding those functions manually?

Comment: FYI, if you can use LINQ, you don't need to define your own `Contains` method.  Just add `using System.Linq;` and you'll be able to use the IEnumerable extension method `Contains` on your `ObservableCollection<T>`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have derived from `ObservableCollection<T>` so `this` is a reference to your collection. All you need is

```
public string Selected
{
    get { return this[SelectedIndex]; }
}
```

and

```
public bool Contains(string str)
{
    return (this.Any(c => (String.Compare(str, c) == 0)));
}
```

Note that `Contains()` [already exists as an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! You're right that `Contains()` already exists as an extension method; however, it uses the Equals on object, which simply checks whether the memory addresses are the same. In contrast, I want to check whether the content of the string is the same.

Comment: In C#, String.Equals(string) compares the value of the string; not the memory address.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve, but you shouldn't inherit from `ObservableCollection<string>`, prefer **composition** over **inheritance**. Actually you've already almost done it (you already have a `private ObservableCollection<string> _strings` member).

See for example: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Back to your initial requirement, if you're doing MVVM, most probably you want to expose *both* a `ObservableCollection<T> MyObjects` property and a `T MySelectedObject` property.